# Django - queryset.union return broken queryset : filter() and get() return everything

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I use `queryset.union` to concatenate two querysets of same nature, but using `.get()` or `.filter()` on the result doesn't work as espected:

```
>>>foo = obj1.father.all()
>>>foo
<QuerySet [<Link: l1>, <Link: l2>]>
>>>foo.get(pk=0)
<Link: l1>
>>>bar = foo.union(obj2.father.all())
>>>bar
<QuerySet [<Link: l1>, <Link: l2>], <Link: l3>], <Link: l4>]>
>>>bar.filter(pk=0)
<QuerySet [<Link: l1>, <Link: l2>], <Link: l3>], <Link: l4>]>
>>>[l.pk for l in bar]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Should I use something else than .union() to concatenate the querysets ? How should I do it ?

my models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                        unique=True,
                        verbose_name = _("Name"),
                        help_text=_("Name of the article"))

class Link(models.Model):
    father = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name="father", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name="child", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Why not `Link.objects.filter(child__in=[obj1, obj2])`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem because I didn't knew I could do that, that's neat !
My original question still stand for my curiosity, why doesn't it work ?

Comment: The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#union)  mention that only count(), order_by(), values(), values_list() and slicing of union queryset is allowed. You can't filter on union queryset.

If you need to filter your queryset, you need to do it before applying union.

Comment: @Priya oh, I was sure I read it well, look like I didn't :( . Thanks, that explain it. (Though I feel like if only those are *allowed* it shouldn't be possible to use others imo...)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union), only count(), order_by(), values(), values_list() and slicing of union queryset is allowed. You can't filter on union queryset.

That means, you have to apply filters on queries before applying union on them.